# Uso de predicate e expressão lambda

Tags: c#, mvvm

Estou estudando WPF e o modelo MVVM pelo seguinte artigo : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Na implementação da interface ICommand, o autor define o seguinte campo:

```
Predicate<object> _canExecute;
```

Quando a classe é instanciada é passado o seguinte parâmetro para esse campo:

```
x => canExecute
```

Minha dúvida é, porque o parâmetro é passado em forma de expressão lambda?

Comment: **TL;DR;** Porque é mais curto, simples, fácil de ler e, além de tudo, mais bonito ***=)***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expressões lambda são muito úteis para criar consultas com LINQ em Visual C#, e nada mais são do que funções anônimas que você pode usar para criar delegates e escrever funções locais que podem ser passadas como argumentos ou retornadas como valor em calls de outras funções.

Um predicate por outro lado é um delegate que retorna um booleano (0 ou 1, V ou F, true or false, yes ou no, sim ou não).

Dessa forma, você pode avaliar que o uso de uma expressão lambda, dado o contexto, é feito porque espera-se de um predicate que retorne um valor booleano, porém este sendo um objeto passado como função (function object), que é típico de um delegate, podendo, portanto, ser passado como parâmetro depois de avaliado mesmo sendo uma função, que é típico das funções ou expressões lambda.